# Graphics[] not working from within For[]

Tags: plotting, graphics

Why is the following code not plotting the set of points from {1,1}
 to {10,10} ?

```
For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++, Graphics[Point[{i, i}]]]
```

Comment: Unless an explicit Return is used, the value returned by For is Null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Graphics[Table[Point[{i, i}], {i, 10}]]
```

If you want to see the output of your command, modify it a little:

```
For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++, Print@Framed@Graphics[Point[{i, i}]]]
```

You will see ten graphics, one point in each one

Comment: also `Graphics[Point@Table[{i, i}, {i, 10}]]`

Comment: what I am actually interested in is generating `i` random points (`For` seems like a good idea when a number of loop repetitions is known) and then plotting them. Could you give me a hint about this?

Comment: @alex Put the loop (in `Table` form) inside the `Graphics`

Comment: @alex So something like: `Graphics[Point@RandomReal[1, {100, 2}]]`?

Comment: I managed to make it work with something like: `ListPlot[Table[{RandomReal[{startRange, endRange}], 
   RandomReal[{min, max}]}, {pointsCount}]]`. Thanks